# Cannot restart SSH daemon after changing sshd_config to port 2222

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I have been looking around and couldn't find a solution to the issue I am having. I am running `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS`, and I followed instructions on the Ubuntu [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openssh-server.html) for changing the SSH port to `2222` by updating the `sshd_config` file.

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 2222
```

When I execute the command `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`, however, I only get the following error:

```
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I then executed the command `systemctl status ssh.service` and got

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-09-07 23:24:04 EDT; 1min 28s ago
  Process: 16813 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 16813 (code=exited, status=255)

Sep 07 23:24:04 sys-0 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Sep 07 23:24:04 sys-0 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Sep 07 23:24:04 sys-0 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Sep 07 23:24:04 sys-0 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 07 23:24:04 sys-0 systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What does the error mean, and how can I address it?

Comment: Most likely you made a simple mistake in your `sshd_config`. What if you put back the original one?

Comment: `sudo sshd -vvvf /etc/ssh/sshd_config` should give you clue as to what is wrong

Comment: When I put back the original one, it works as usual. However, port `2222` worked for me today doing the exact same thing I did last night. Very odd.

Comment: @techraf I deleted the other one. I'm never sure which SE is better for this type of question

Comment: @Paul on openssh-server 1:7.4p1-10+deb9u2 on Debian 9 I get `unknown option -- v`.

Answer (score 18):

As [@techraf said](https://superuser.com/questions/1122125/cannot-restart-ssh-daemon-after-changing-sshd-config-to-port-2222/1291078#comment1603601_1122125), most likely you made a simple mistake in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Try [sshd test mode](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/checking-openssh-sshd-configuration-syntax-errors.html):

```
$ sudo sshd -t
/etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 1: Bad configuration option: sds
```

From [man page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#t):

- `-t` **Test mode**. Only check the validity of the configuration file and sanity of the keys. This is useful for updating sshd reliably as configuration options may change.
- `-T` **Extended test mode**. Check the validity of the configuration file, output the effective configuration to stdout and then exit. Optionally, Match rules may be applied by specifying the connection parameters using one or more [`-C` options](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd).

Answer (score 3):

Are you running on a system that utilizes `SELinux`? It could be that this is denying the port bind; try adding in a new rule.

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2222
```

Comment: no, I am not running on `SELinux`, but somehow this morning doing the same things worked. Thanks so much for your input

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same error. After banging my head against the wall for a while I've found out, that I've destroyed the `/etc/passwd` entries by running a custom-made-linux-server-setup-bash-script which worked well previously, but this time the regex within the "sed" command erased all the existing entries :D 
After copy pasting the default entries from another working linux server I could finally restart sshd.

So don't forget to backup the original `/etc/passwd` file before applying any regex replacements on it :)

Answer (score -2):

Edit `sshd_config`

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and comment this line:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

I mean change that to:

```
# Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: Still the same error, nothing has changed

Comment: How is this related to the question?